# License for package Android SDK Build-Tools not accepted

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 958 ms

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
> File C:\Users\toshiba.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
> **Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.**
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\toshiba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
> **Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.**

Answer (score 17):

You need to update SDk tools for remove "License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted"
Follow below steps:

Open Android Studio, Tools > Sdk Manager > Android SDK Command-Line Tools

Thanks